# Get data into one form field based on another's field in access 2003

Tags: database, ms-access, forms

I am trying to update existing form field based on another combo box selection.

I have a DB with such relations: http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/7396/relationse.jpg

I have a such form: http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/9758/getdata.jpg
Which Offers to select only existing IDs in database.

All i want to do is when user selects (change) existing combo box "Filmas_ID" value, in nearby input box with value "Unbound" shows up data related to this ID (You know - Just for informative reasons).

```
(SELECT Filmas.Nosaukums FROM Filmas WHERE Filmas_ID = combo box "Filmas_ID" value; )
```

It looks very simple, but i had no success yet to get it work.
Thanks for your help! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few handy ways to do this, one involves including the data in the combo. Let us say the combo is set up like so:

```
RowSource : SELECT Filmas_ID, Nosaukums FROM Filmas 
ColumnCount : 2
```

You now have a choice of setting the column widths so that filmas_id is selected, but Nosaukums is shown in the combo. Alternatively, you can set the textbox to reference the combo column, like so:

```
= mycombo.column(1)
```

Where columns count from zero.

Another method is to use DlookUp in the control source of the textbox:

```
= DLookUp("Nosaukums","Filmas", "Filmas_ID = " & mycombo)
```

Where Filmas_ID is numeric and the required value is in the bound column of the combo.